# Is this possible with an htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I am wondering if this is possible to do with an .htaccess rule.

My beginning url:
http://cmfi.org/wherewework/missionary/?missionary=ttaho%2C

What I want to end up with:
http://cmfi.org/wherewework/missionary/ttaho

The ttaho will change according to the page.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: It is definitely possible as that's exactly the kind of thing mod_rewrite does, but it's not clear what you want to do. "beginning URL" and "what I want to end up with" can be interpreted in a couple of ways and each requires different rules. Try clicking on the ".htaccess" tag in your question to get a list of related questions here. Browse through those to find examples that you can work with, then update your question here with code if you've tried some of those and are having trouble getting them to work.

Comment: Agree with @DavidRavetti. It seems you want to remove the query and pass the parameters as part of the URL-path, to a script in `.../wherewework`. Right? Why the `%2C` in the "beginning url", though?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think I was asking anyone to code this for me...Just asking if it was possible. I have tried a few things and couldn't get them to work. The %2c is an encoded part of the url that is added from the plugin I was using.

I will figure it out. No worries.